# Get-ChildItem (gci) | select-string (pattern) fails over remote invoke-command (icm)

Tags: powershell

My goal (simplified) is to find phone-numbers from a remote user.

The second part of the command after "`{`", is successful when ran locally on the host machine, but does not work when running remotely:

```
icm -cn <ip-addr> -cr <username> {
     gci -path C:\Users\IEUser\Downloads | select-string -Pattern "\d{3}-\d{4}" -AllMatches
}
```

I have no errors returned, just blank space.
I have successfully ran other remote (icm) commands.
Please let me know if there is a fix to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring -cn -and -cr, which are missing parameter values, select-string over invoke-command doesn't format right.  Here's an example that can be run over an elevated prompt.  The object is still there.  You can use select-object or format-* commands to see it, either inside or outside the scriptblock.  Or use where-object instead of select-object.

```
icm localhost { 'hi' | select-string hi | fc } 

hi
```

Comment: SOLVED --
Thank you @js2010

just needed " | fc " before the end of the script-block. 

icm -cn <ip-addr> -cr <username> {
gci -path C:\Users\IEUser\Downloads | select-string -Pattern "\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}" -AllMatches | fc}

Answer (score 0):

credit to js2010

I just needed " | fc " before the end of the script-block:

icm -cn  -cr  { gci -path C:\Users\IEUser\Downloads | select-string -Pattern "\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}" -AllMatches | fc}